# Инструкция jmp в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Извиняюсь за возможно тупой вопрос, но мне непонятно как это работает. Допустим у нас есть x86 процессор и мы выполняем jmp на какой либо адрес. Насколько я знаю эта инструкция занимает в памяти 5 байт. jmp (1 байт) + адрес(4 байта). Только мне не понятно как процессор считывает эту самую инструкцию, ведь размер регистров для x86 - 4 байта, а размер нашей инструкции - 5 байт. Получается, чтобы прочитать эту инструкцию процессору требуется 2 такта, так как она полностью не помещается в регистр. Я знаю что скорее всего это не так, но мне не понятно как это работает. Не могли бы вы мне объяснить что к чему. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: А кто тебе сказал, что команда загружается в регистры процессора?

Comment: @Akina,  я всегда думал, что процессор "напрямую"  не работает с оперативной памятью. Мне кажется информация сначала попадает в какой-нибудь регистр, и только потом процессор ее исполняет. Объясните пожалуйста, в чем я не  прав

Comment: Команда перед выполнением загружается в [конвейер команд процессора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80), а не в регистры.

Comment: *я всегда думал, что процессор "напрямую" не работает с оперативной памятью.* Ну да... а контроллер прямого доступа к памяти - по ошибке так назвали :-)

Comment: `контроллер прямого доступа к памяти` это чуть о другом. Эта штука позволяет устройствам ввода-вывода (типа диска) обращаться к памяти в _обход_ процессора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При запуске программы, процессор передаёт контролёру памяти MMU адрес точки-входа в код, после чего чтением из ОЗУ занимается уже контролёр. Размер шины памяти DDR = 64-бита (8 байт), и контролёр читает из неё в пакетном режиме "Burst-Length" сразу по 64-байта данных, т.е. один раз ставит указатель на начало блока памяти, и повторяет операцию чтения 8-раз (8х8=64). Эти 64-байта прямиком попадают в одну линейку кэш-памяти L3 (cache-line), и на каждом такте продвигаются дальше к исполнительному ядру процессора Executive.

В исполнительном ядре инструкции анализируются (расщепляются на микро-инструкции Mops), и только если эта инструкция подразумевает какой-нибудь расчёт, то они попадают в регистры процессора, иначе их исполняет само ядро. В случае-же с инструкцией JMР, опкод её поглощается ядром, а 4-байтный адрес записывается в регистр EIP (Instruction Pointer). Это приводит к тому, что процессор прыгает на указанный в JMP адрес.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ширина входа в процессор Skylake 16 байт за один такт, то есть за один так процессор может прочитать три таких команды.
2. Данные содержащиеся непосредственно "внутри" команд попадают в регистры только если так прямо указанно в самой команде, при этом "командная" часть будет отброшена на аппаратном уровне.